# Error while installing Skype

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, skype, error-handling

I have been following the guide [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-skype-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux-64-bit).
And i am getting this error;

```
 dpkg: error processing package skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160523-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
```

I have tried everything that is mentioned at the link but I cannot install skype. 
There is no output for `dpkg --configure -a` and the output for `sudo apt-get -f install` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaudio2:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient20:i386
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386
  libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 qt-at-spi:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I have removed the packages which are not required.

Output of `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade` is:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                       
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                       
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [2,376 B]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [2,320 B]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [980 B]
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Fetched 5,676 B in 3s (1,858 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Sources (partner/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:6
W: Target Sources (partner/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (partner/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:6
W: Target Sources (partner/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php7.0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php7.0 all 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 [36.9 kB]
Fetched 36.9 kB in 0s (41.2 kB/s) 
(Reading database ... 241030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0_7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0 (7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) over (7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) ...
Setting up php7.0 (7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) ...
```

if i use `sudo apt-get install skype` it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and i have tried all the methods to fix broken packages. NONE of them work.

```
apt-cache policy skype skype-bin gives:
skype:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Version table:
     4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner amd64 Packages
     4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages
skype-bin:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Version table:
     4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner i386 Packages
     4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages
```

and `sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @ByteCommander i have edited my post with the outputs. thank you

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @ByteCommander i have edited my post....its quite long though

Comment: Why don't you try the first installation option on that link? It is also suggested in here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Comment: @B.Turan i have edited my post. please see

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy skype skype-bin` say and what about `sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Please see.

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install skype:i386 skype-bin:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386`?

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please SAVE ME!!....i have an interview today

Comment: You can go on by always adding the packages about which it says that they are not going to be installed to the install command. Next one to try would be `sudo apt-get install skype:i386 skype-bin:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a no command line installation option. I did it as a dummy user. Hope it helps.
1. Browse to https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
2. Choose Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch) from the drop-down menu

[image: Image 1]

3. Let it download..
4. After finishing the download, just click the file from the browser

[image: Image 2]

5. Install it to your system, you will be required admin authorisation and etc.

[image: Image 3]

6. After completion of the installation, just find the app and open it.

[image: Image 4]

7. My sample Ubuntu Desktop was like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried this and it does not install skype. There is no error but it just doesnt install it.